# sql query for filtering record in jsp

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

Hi this sql query is not working in some conditions.Whenever i write

```
query += " Price<? and Size<? and Type=?";
```

out of the if statement then it is working but when i put within the if statement then it doesn't work. And when i am trying print the variable query when it is outside the if statement then it show the message like this

```
select  * from products where  Price<? and Size<? and Type=?
```

I am not able to understand it please help me out 
this is the whole code`

```
 public List<Products> Filter_Items(String[] Brand, String[] Flavour,float Price,float Size,String Type)
{

    ResultSet rs;
    List<Products> data = null;
    PreparedStatement stmt;
    try {
        StringBuilder param = new StringBuilder();
        if (Brand != null) {
            for (String str : Brand) {
                param.append("'").append(str).append("', ");
            }
        }
        StringBuilder param1 = new StringBuilder();
        if (Flavour != null) {
            for (String str : Flavour) {
                param1.append("'").append(str).append("', ");
            }
        }

        String prm = param.toString().length() > 2 ? param.toString()
                .substring(0, param.toString().length() - 2) : null;
        String prm1 = param1.toString().length() > 2 ? param1.toString()
                .substring(0, param1.toString().length() - 2) : null;

        String query = "select  * from products where ";


      if(Price!=0 && Size!=0 && Type!=null && prm != null && prm1 != null)
       {
           query+="Brand in (" + prm + ") and Flavour in (" + prm1 + ") and";
            query += " Price<? and Size<? and Type=?";

        }



       System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
           System.out.println(query);

        stmt = DataBaseConnection.DBConn.getConnection().prepareStatement(query);
        stmt.setFloat(1, Price);
        stmt.setFloat(2, Size);
        stmt.setString(3, Type);
        rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        if (rs != null) {
            data = new ArrayList<Products>();
            while (rs.next()) {
                Products p = new Products();
                p.setTitle(rs.getString("Ttile"));
                p.setCategory(rs.getString("Category"));
                p.setSubCategory(rs.getString("SubCategory"));
                p.setSubCategoryTwo(rs.getString("SubCategorytwo"));
                p.setPrice(rs.getInt("Price"));
                p.setFlavour(rs.getString("Flavour"));
                p.setSize(rs.getFloat("Size"));
                p.setImage(rs.getString("image"));
                p.setBrand(rs.getString("Brand"));
                p.setInstock(rs.getString("instock"));
                p.setInstockQty(rs.getInt("instockqty"));
                p.setType(rs.getString("Type"));
                data.add(p);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

        System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
        System.out.println("----------------------");
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        System.out.println("----------------------");
        System.out.println(e.getSuppressed());
        System.out.println("----------------------");
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Error aa gai bhai ");
        return null;
    }
    return data;

}
```

User may not select the brand or size so the value of any of them may be `null` so I have create different `if` conditions. How to achieve this?

---

EDIT:

This code doesn't work when I don't select any value from my JSP. I'm getting `NullPointerException`. This is the servlet code that calls my method:

```
public class My extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        float Price = 0, Size = 0;
        Price = Float.parseFloat(request.getParameter("Price"));
        Size = Float.parseFloat(request.getParameter("size"));
        String Type = request.getParameter("type");
        String[] Brand = request.getParameterValues("Brand");
        String[] Flavour = request.getParameterValues("Flavour");

        List<Products> data = new SessionBeanClass().Filter_Itemsl(Brand, Flavour, Price, Size, Type);
        request.setAttribute("Products", data);
        ;
        request.getRequestDispatcher("sample2.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

Comment: Can you post the query string just before execution.

Comment: and the stack trace if it's producing one?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza which is why i said *if* it's producing one. "It's not working" can mean an awful lot round here.

Comment: It seems the condition `if(Price!=0 && Size!=0 && Type!=null && prm != null && prm1 != null)` returned a `'false'`.

Comment: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0)

Comment: I have debugged my code and now reached to conclusion when i put Qery+ in if then it's not working but if i put outside then it's working

Comment: @user3660263: It is obviously would be a `'0'` when the `if` condition did not satisfy.

Comment: but i have more conditions because user may not select the brand or size so the value of any of them may be null so i have create different  if conditions that is why i want to put it outside the if block

Comment: Ok, so your real problem is how to build this statement by allowing multiple parameters that may or not may be fulfilled. This is what you should have asked from the beginning.

Comment: yes sir ... sorry for delay

Comment: can you help me out ????//

Comment: can anyone explain???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To build the query dynamically, it is better to:

- Evaluate each field by its own
- Have a `List<Object>` that will store all the parameters to pass to your query.

The implementation will look like this:

```
List<Object> parameters = new ArrayList<>();
/*
    Parameter to evaluate:
    String[] Brand, String[] Flavour,float Price,float Size,String Type
*/
StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder("SELECT * FROM products WHERE 1=1");
if (Brand != null) {
    query.append(" AND brand in (");
    for (int i = 0; i < Brand.length; i++) {
        query.append('?');
        if (i < Brand.length - 1) {
            query.append(',');
        }
        parameters.add(Brand[i]);
    }
    query.append(")");
}
if (Flavour != null) {
    query.append(" AND Flavour in (");
    for (int i = 0; i < Flavour .length; i++) {
        query.append('?');
        if (i < Flavour.length - 1) {
            query.append(',');
        }
        parameters.add(Flavour[i]);
    }
    query.append(")");
}
if (Price != 0) {
    query.append(" AND Price < ?");
    parameters.add(Price);
}
if (Size != 0) {
    query.append(" AND Size < ?");
    parameters.add(Size);
}
if (Type != null) {
    query.append(" AND Type = ?");
    parameters.add(Type);
}
//prepare the statement
stmt = DataBaseConnection.DBConn.getConnection().prepareStatement(query);
//append the parameters
int i = 1;
for (Object parameter : parameters) {
    stmt.setObject(i++, parameter);
}
//execute the dynamic query
rs = stmt.executeQuery();
if (rs != null) {
    //rest of your code
}
```

---

From your edit. The problem is here:

```
Price = Float.parseFloat(request.getParameter("Price"));
```

Since you're not sending the data for "Price" parameter, `request.getParameter("Price")` returns `null`. Then, the code to be executed will be `Float.parseFloat(null)`, which gives `NullPointerException` for passing a `null` value as parameter.

The solution is to store the result of `request.getParameter("Price")` in a variable and evaluate the variable:

```
String priceParameter = request.getParameter("Price");
priceParameter = (priceParameter == null) ? "0" : priceParameter.trim();
Price = Float.parseFloat(priceParameter);
```

Similar for other variables that need conversion.

Comment: thnaks a lot for your help ..I try if it works for me

Comment: your code is not working sir .. showing null pointer exception

Comment: @user3660263 care to at least post the stacktrace in your question?

Comment: @user3660263 I don't know the bigger picture. AFAIK this piece of code as is won't throw a `NullPointerException` unless another external variable like `DataBaseConnection.DBConn.getConnection()` returns `null`.

Comment: NO SIR YOU FORGOT CLOSE THE BRACE IN BRAND IN(' WHEN I DID IT WORKED BUT NOW IT WORKING WHEN SELECT FEW PARAMETERS BUT IT DOESN'T WORK WHEN I SELECT BRAND OR FLAVOR OR PRICE OR SIZE ALONE

Comment: @user3660263 first: **never** post a comment using caps only, or are you yelling at me? second: that won't throw `NullPointerException` but an sql exception for wrong sql statement. Answer updated and code fixed.

Comment: Ok don't be angry please sir. I am not yelling at you just telling what happened. It's working fine  when none of parameters are null. but if pass brand only and rest of them are null then it throws Null pointer exception.and not even printing the stack trace

Comment: @user3660263 ok, checked the code and fixed it. Please check.

Comment: not working sir .still same problem not working if rest are null and only one is not null

Comment: @user3660263 I find this very odd. Please update your question by adding the current code and the relevant stacktrace to analyze the problem.

Answer (score 0):

public class My extends HttpServlet {

```
/**
 * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
 * methods.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    float Price = 0, Size = 0;
    Price = Float.parseFloat(request.getParameter("Price"));
    Size = Float.parseFloat(request.getParameter("size"));
    String Type = request.getParameter("type");
    String[] Brand = request.getParameterValues("Brand");
    String[] Flavour = request.getParameterValues("Flavour");

    List<Products> data = new SessionBeanClass().Filter_Itemsl(Brand, Flavour, Price, Size, Type);
    request.setAttribute("Products", data);
    ;
    request.getRequestDispatcher("sample2.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

}

Comment: And the stacktrace is... Note that this should be part of your question, not an answer.

Comment: Then the problem may be somewhere else. Please debug through this code to check where the `NullPointerException` arises.

Comment: Wait, you didn't fix this part: `for (int i = 0; i < Brand.length; i++)`. This `for` is placed two times, the second is wrong, it should be `for (int i = 0; i < Flavour.length; i++)`.

Comment: Ok, just debug through your code and let me know which line of **this method** throws the `NullPointerException`.

Comment: it is not showing stack trace on error i am confused

Comment: I don't want to be annoying but have you tried setting up some debug breakpoints, using the debugger, calling your method with the `null` parameters and step through every line of code of this method to check where the `NullPointerException` or other error arises?

Comment: well i tried printing query and value of parameters

Comment: Ok, try this instead (since looks like you don't want to debug the code): Add `System.out.println()` statements between blocks of code, something like `System.out.println("step 1 finished"); (...) `System.out.println("step 2 finished")`;` and on. Then, let me know in which step the code stopped working.

Comment: I tried when i pass only brand it not even entering in the function i guess. i put first line in function as STARTING POINT it's not printing that line

Comment: shuold post the code of servlet from where i am calling the function

Comment: That should be part of another question. You could still maintain this question as unresolved i.e. do not accept an answer, because you cannot prove that this code works for your needs.

Comment: I think i got the answer because i am passing value of brand and flavor as any array because i am using check box. i tried accessing the servlet without calling the function, so if i leave brand or flavor unchecked then it shows me null pointer exception. Don't you think that is the reason

Comment: I would need to check the code of the servlet. Please update your code. I'll try to solve it here.

Comment: Problem spotted: `Price = Float.parseFloat(request.getParameter("Price"));`. You will get a `NullPointerException` if trying to parse a `null` argument.

Comment: but i have initialized them

Comment: Looks like you're very new to programming, so I'll explain this in details. `request.getParameter("Price")` returns `null` since you haven't set the value for `"Price"` argument. Then, `Float.parseFloat(request.getParameter("Price"))` becomes `Float.parseFloat(null)`, and this line throws `NullPointerException`, breaking your code. Again, this can be easily notified if using a debugger (not to be annoying but seriously the debugger is your best friend to spot these errors).

Comment: Ok thanks sir 
what code should i write on servlet part 
a last help from you side

Comment: thank you so much sir Luggi you are really a saver .
i might need your help in future i know you will.i need to complete this project very soon .this is my first project 
thank again..